# How do I use another database other than default in play-framework?

Tags: database, scala, playframework-2.3

Up until I was using only one database in my application. So for any sql query, I was just using the default database. Below is given the info about the database.

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="postgres://user:password@localhost:5439/database_name"
```

These info are saved in the appliction.conf file. In the code below DB is the default database.

```
DB.withConnection {
  conn =>
    {
      val statement = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)
      try {
        statement.execute(sql)
      }
      catch {
        case e: Exception => Logger.debug("There is some error with the database")
      }
    }
}
```

But I need to use another database. Below is given the info about the database.

```
db.um.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.um.url="mysql://user:password@localhost:3306/database_name"
```

These info are also saved in the application.conf file. Now how do I access that database and run an sql command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data source called `default`, as the name suggests, is used as a default value for all connections. You can see that the [withConnection()](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.db.DB$) method takes a parameter with a data source name but if nothing is passed, "default" is used instead.

To use your additional data source you have to specify it as a parameter of the withConnection() method.

```
DB.withConnection("um") { conn =>
  // implement your action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is like myself, is looking to use multiple data resources in Play 2.6: This is not the answer.

We need to define the name of the database when we inject the instance of the `Database`, using `@NamedDatabase`:

```
class Customer @Inject()(@NamedDatabase("customer") db: Database){ ??? }
```